# TypeError: Cannot find function getCell in object Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am completely new to coding anything related to Google Apps Script and JavaScript in general.

I've adapted a script to my needs, but I am getting the following error when I run it:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getCell in object Sheet

Essentially, I am trying to get the value in cell D4 (4,4) and pass that value to the variable `emailTo`. I'm obviously not doing it correctly. The rest of the script should work fine. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
// Sends PDF receipt
// Based on script by ixhd at https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885

// Load a menu item called "Receipt" with a submenu item called "E-mail Receipt"
// Running this, sends the currently open sheet, as a PDF attachment
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"E-mail Receipt", functionName:"exportSomeSheets"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Receipt', submenu);  
}

function exportSomeSheets() {
  // Set the Active Spreadsheet so we don't forget
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Set the message to attach to the email.
  var message = "Thank you for attending !  Please find your receipt attached.";

  // Construct the Subject Line
  var subject = "Receipt";

  // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
  // Pull e-mail address from D4 to send receipt to
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var emailTo = sheet.getCell(4, 4).getValue();

  // Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
  var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);

  // Find and delete the default "Sheet 1"
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

  // Make the PDF called "Receipt.pdf"
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'Receipt.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Send the  constructed email 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});

  // Delete the wasted sheet
  DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  
}
```

Comment: Use sheet.getRange instead of getCell.

Comment: When writing code in the script editor you can use the auto complete feature (control + space) to avoid this kind of error as it will show you all possible and valid available methods.

Comment: Use `getRange(4,4,1,1)` or use `getRange("D4")`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `getCell()` is a method of `Range`, not `Sheet`. Get a `Range` from the `Sheet`, then use `getCell()` on the `Range` object

Comment: The bit about `Sheet` not having a `getCell()` method is absolutely right.