# Email notification: TypeError: Cannot find function getColumn in object 1

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to write this function that will be used in google sheet so that whenever a value is changed in a specific cell, it will send an email notification to say that cell has been changed. The problem lies is when I used this code in a google sheet there is an error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot find function getColumn in object 1"
```

Im not sure what is causing this and I have attempted to look at other peoples problems similar to this but I just dont understand why it is doing this.
Code:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
    var range = e.range;

    if (e.getColumn() == 11)
    {
        var previous = range.offset(0, -1);
        var next = range.offset(0, 1);
        var emailAddress = 'myemail@gmail.com';
        var message = 'Data Changed';
        var subject = 'Test Awareness Mail';
        GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is getColumn()  function? where is it

Comment: getColumn() is mean to  "Returns the starting column position for this range."
this is used in my if statement to look for the column "K" 
Link has to function in it
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: [check here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getColumn())  i think the problem is e is not your spreadsheet, so this function is undefined, it has to be of spreadsheet

Comment: Thats what i thought originally but when i strip this down to this code, it allows it and even leave the note down, but when i try to just send an email or put an if statement in there it doesnt work. as shown below, this code works



"
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;  
  range.setNote('preif');

}"

Comment: try with range.getColumn() see what you get, log it

Comment: I tried that, but no response when i try to make a change in the spreadsheet, I then place the if statement in its on function to see if its the its still getColumn(), and it still comes up with the error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getColumn" of undefined."

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14784448/2996989) could be similar problem, see if it helps

Comment: I have already seen that post, although its similar it doesnt address mine and doesnt give me hints on why mine doesnt work. although i do appreicate the help!